# Keras error compiling node

Tags: python, theano, keras

I am trying to train a small CNN using Keras with the `ImageDataGenerator` like so:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(IM_HEIGHT, IM_WIDTH, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    rotation_range=40,
    fill_mode='nearest')

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    SPLIT_TRAIN_DIR,
    target_size=(IM_HEIGHT, IM_WIDTH),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    SPLIT_VALIDATION_DIR,
    target_size=(IM_HEIGHT, IM_WIDTH),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator, samples_per_epoch=32, nb_epoch=3, verbose=1,
    validation_data=validation_generator, nb_val_samples=800)
```

I am trying to solve a binary classification problem, but I'm getting the following error

> Exception: ('The following error happened while compiling the node',
>   GpuElemwise{RoundHalfToEven,no_inplace}(GpuSoftmaxWithBias.0)

followed by a large amount of cuda options. The line this is failing at is

```
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator, samples_per_epoch=32, nb_epoch=3, verbose=1,
    validation_data=validation_generator, nb_val_samples=800)
```

I am completely lost as to what this could be, I've tried several different architectures for the cnn, I've also verified that thte ImageDataGenerator works fine. I have not been able to figure out what the problem could be.

I'm using Python 3.6.0, Theano 0.8.2 and Keras 1.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some more digging I found a seemingly unrelated [issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5408), but that had the same error message.

Apparently, this is an issue with the particular version of Theano, and had already been fixed in the master branch. Running

```
pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/Theano/Theano.git#egg=Theano
```

solved my problem.